# Force starting point of lines()

Tags: r, lines

Perhaps because the question is so basic, the keywords that I can think up for this question all directs me to other things. I am trying to draw a graph with spiky curve lines that connect the medians. The real data is very big, but the starting values are duplicates of (0,0):

```
DATA<-data.frame(time<-c(sort(rep(c(0,2,4,8,12),4))),
                 conc<-c(rep(0,4),rnorm(n=4,mean=30),
                        rnorm(n=4,mean=10),
                        rnorm(n=4,mean=35),
                        rnorm(n=4,mean=15)))
# Create blank graph
plot(NULL,NULL,xlab="Time",ylab="Conc",
     xlim=c(0,15),ylim=c(0,40),main="Example")
# Add line
require(quantreg)
require(plyr)
require(MatrixModels)
DATA<-plyr::arrange(DATA,time)
fit3<-rqss(DATA$conc~qss(DATA$time,constraint="N"),tau=0.5,data = DATA)
lines(unique(DATA$time)[-1],fit3$coef[1] + fit3$coef[-1],lwd=2)
```

As you can see, the line does not connect to the starting (0,0) values and instead start at the next lowest level.
I was tempted to cheat, but it does not connect to the lines and I would really prefer to work it out with the rest of the code instead of trying to pass off two lines as one:

```
# Cheating getaway but does not work well, segments are not connected
segments(x0=0,y0=0,x1=2,y1=30,lwd=2)
```

Some relevant answers that I found were not appropriate for my situation. 
[Line in R plot should start at a different timepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877479/line-in-r-plot-should-start-at-a-different-timepoint) for example suggest modifying the data, which would not help to extend my line and plus my actual data is too big that I would be wary to do this kind of manipulation. I would not want to use `plot(x,y,type="l")` even though it goes through the (0,0) point, because 1) it looks bad on the huge data, and 2) I would have to overlay another similar line using `lines()`. I wonder whether it has more to do with `rqss` and less with `lines`?

I apologize if this has already been asked before.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.. you just want an additional segment from {0,0} to the first segment? like this? `lines(c(0, unique(DATA$time)[-1]),c(0, fit3$coef[1] + fit3$coef[-1]),lwd=2)`

Comment: Since the first value of `DATA$time` is 0, instead of omitting it with `[-1]` then re-adding it with `c(0, ...)` you can just make the first argument `unique(DATA$time)`. You will still need the `c(0, ...` for the y values (second argument).

Comment: @Gregor Thank you both. Would either of you want to Answer the main question so I can select you as my answer?

Comment: I'll leave it to @rawr, he was the one who figured out what you wanted. Though if he doesn't do it very soon feel free to write up a nice answer yourself.

Comment: I think, from a place of understanding, it's just hard to understand *not* thinking of adding 0's to the start of your x and y vectors if you want the line to start a (0, 0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73893/discussion-between-shirleywu-and-gregor).